Presenting a poster about work that has already been published
I am planning to participate in a conference for the first time. Are there any rules or conventions that prevent me from showcasing results that have already been published?

Do you need to submit your proposal to the committee?

@Buffy Yes, I must submit an abstract  that will be in the Book of Abstracts of the conference

Speaking as a chemist: I would actually strongly suggest that you go ahead and show already-published work as a useful perspective for those who may not have seen that specific publication and as motivation for future work. The one caveat would be to show at least some work that you or your group/institution has done (past or current). Showing just others' work as a way of gaining presentation experience isn't the most ethical choice.
You can strengthen your poster by joining together previous work in a way that suggests a new idea, or a new way of relating disparate ideas. As others have said, be sure to attribute the old work. I have seen posters that highlight a significant piece of old work and then say "See this? It shows we need to do more work as a field into X, Y, and Z." Interesting and useful conversations come out of this. You can also show old work and reinterpret it in a new way, even going as far as to say that original conclusions were wrong or limited.
To more concretely answer your question: You should be careful of any work that might be legally restricted because of ongoing patents, intellectual property disputes, or classification. And be sure to correctly cite any funding awards, which may have changed since the previous work was done.

You can submit a proposal, being honest about what you intend. The committee will judge its appropriateness. In many CS conferences, poster sessions tend to be about work in progress, not past work. They give early-career researchers (doctoral students especially) a way to meet more experienced conference goers and get feedback on the work and some ideas as well.
You can also, and probably should, ask the "program chair" or equivalent about what you'd like to do.
The committee might see it as an advertisement for your work and reject it, but that is up to them. There are no ethical issues in a submission, however.
Look at past proceedings for the conference you want to submit to and get an idea of what they find acceptable. Don't bother them with something obviously out of scope.

Ok. I am in a chemistry field. Don’t have any ongoing projects right now that fit the scope, so I wish to show published outcomes as reference. If this is not unethical or against publishing agreements and committee agree on, then it’s fine, right?

The committee sets the agenda and determines what fits and what doesn't. If they approve it, then it is fine. Just be honest in your abstract that this is prior/published work.

yes, sure. Will add QR code if someone’s interested in delving into the manuscript itself

Also, name and cite the work.

Well, yeah. As a regular reference I would make in a full-text manuscript
